# Unable to select days and hours when minDate and maxDate are on the same days with Eonasdan datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I got an odd behaviour when using [bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) v. 4.17.47.
Here is my picker configuration:

```
format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm',
showTodayButton: true,
useCurrent: false,
showClear: true,
minDate: moment('{{ ts_beg }}'),
maxDate: moment('{{ ts_end }}')
```

When setting minDate and maxDate to the same day but with different hours, let's say `2018-2-1 00:00` and `2018-2-1 02:00`, I am unable to choose both date and time:
[image: peek 2018-02-05 09-33]

Does anyone has a workaround to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem, if not wrong, is because of the implementation of `maxDate` you can override this behavior using the [functions](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#minmaxdate), this way you will be able to select the date

Here a live example:

```js
const format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm';
const MaxDate = moment('2018-02-01 02:00', format);
const MinDate = moment('2018-02-01 00:00', format);
$('#myDatepicker').datetimepicker({
  format: format,
  showTodayButton: true,
  useCurrent: false,
  showClear: true,
  minDate: MinDate,
});

$('#myDatepicker').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(MaxDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/25c11d79/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<br/>
<!--Space for the fiddle-->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group date' id='myDatepicker'>
          <input type='text' class="form-control" />
          <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect answer !